# CiviMail shows unexpected groups when selecting recipients

Tags: civimail, email, acl

I create a new email and go to choose "Recipients". I see a full list of all groups. This includes groups I shouldn't be allowed to see (per ACL rules), and groups that do not have the "mailing list" attribute. Does a little trick exist that can restrict the groups available to choose from?

Edit: CiviCRM version: 4.6.3

Comment: Which Civi version? I wonder if this is a regression similar to [Basic Search form group select does not respect ACLs](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16836).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar issue is filed [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13644) for which I've submitted a PR at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6366

Hope you can see Groups permitted by ACL now:)

Update : If you can also see the groups not configured for mailing list, please upgrade to the latest CiviCRM version.

Comment: Editing those two files with your suggested fixes resolved my issue! Thank you so much. It seems to also resolve the issue with seeing the non-mailing lists. Not sure why, but who am I to ask at this point :)

Comment: @EricH I've updated the PR as some the test were failing. I recommend you to please use the latest changes in order to avoid other conflicts. Thanks.

Comment: I have now done so. My version of api/v3/Group.php didn't match yours exactly (probably because I'm still on 4.6.3, not 4.6.5) but the code still works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug to me, at least for the ACLs. I am quite surprised that you can see groups that have not been flagged as "mailing list". Can you please provide specifics on the version you are using, as well as the way you have setup these ACLs? Also, on the Manage Groups screen, do you see the same groups or a different list? Finally, do users that have different ACLs than yours have the same issue?

Comment: v4.6.3

ACLs
Role "Org 1 Staff" created & assigned group with the same name
Role "Org 1 Staff" allowed to edit the group "Org 1 Universe"
Role "Org 1 Staff" allowed to edit the group "Org 1 Staff" (Access Control)
Role "Org 1 Staff" allowed to edit the group "Org 1 Emails" (Mailing List)
Also, three ACLs apply to Everyone, all are custom fields.

As admin, I can see all above groups plus those belonging to Org 1, Org 2, Org 3, etc. on Manage Groups. 

As Org 1 staff (incognito), I see only Org 1 groups in Manage Groups, but see all in CiviMail. Staff in all groups have the same experience.